# How do I stop regex from filtering out 2 digits out of 4?

Tags: python, regex, datetime, python-datetime

My code is:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
try:
    print(s)
    if(re.match('(\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2})[/-](\d{2})', s)):
        year = '19'+re.search('(\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2})[/-](\d{2})', s).group(3)
        date = re.search('(\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2})[/-](\d{2})', s).group(1)+'/'+re.search('(\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2})[/-](\d{2})', s).group(2)+'/'+year
        print(date)
        return pd.to_datetime(date)
    else:
        result = parse(s, fuzzy_with_tokens=True, default=datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1))
        print("S: ",s)
        print("Result: ", result[0])
        return(result[0])
except Exception:
    pass
```

I am trying to process 04/09/2009 in the else block but since the if part matches 2 digits in 2009, the code never gets to the else part. I am not sure how to make regex match 2 digits in the year part passed and go to else if its more that 2 digits in the year.

Comment: If there is nothing else after the date in the string `s` you can add the end of line character to your regex `$` to only match strings with exactly 2 digits for the year

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks for your quick reply. I have tried doing:
```re.match('(\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2})[/-](\d{2})$', s)```
but that does not help either. The code still jumps to the else part

Comment: Isn't it supposed to since there are 4 digits in the year?

Comment: I was looking for a date in the format 4/6/09. But its figured out now. Thanks for all the help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `$` to indicate the end of the string. Below is the updated if clause

```
s_list = ['04/09/09', '04/09/2009']
for s in s_list:
    if(re.match('(\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2})[/-](\d{2}$)', s)):
        print("We are at if: {0}".format(s))
    else:
        print("We are at else: {0}".format(s))
```

Output:

```
We are at if: 04/09/09
We are at else: 04/09/2009
```